# Drawing a line on a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, graphics2d

I am trying to draw a line using the `Graphics` 2D but then the line appears  over all the 
other components in the `JFrame` thus making them invisible. How do I correct this problem?

Here's the code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

class Success extends JFrame{

    public Success(){
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setSize(450,450);

        JButton button =new JButton("press");
        panel.add(button);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Line2D lin = new Line2D.Float(100, 100, 250, 260);
        g2.draw(lin);
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        Success s=new Success();
        s.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot?

Comment: How should the problem be corrected? What would you like your program to do?

Comment: I could not understand, you drawing a line on your `JFrame`, then you adding components on your `JFrame`, so what this line is for, if you want to hide this with your components. Instead draw this line by extending `JPanel` and overriding `paintComponent(...)`, so that it can be visible, along with other components :-) Just for drawing a line, one shouldn't simply override `paint(...)` method, try to override `paintComponent(...)` by drawing on top of a `JComponent/JPanel`

Comment: when the application starts a line as well as the button is displayed all in the same frame

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

class Success extends JFrame{

    public Success(){
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setSize(450,450);

        JButton button =new JButton("press");
        panel.add(button);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);  // fixes the immediate problem.
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Line2D lin = new Line2D.Float(100, 100, 250, 260);
        g2.draw(lin);
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        Success s=new Success();
        s.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

### Further tips

1. Create the GUI on the EDT.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.
2. Use a `JPanel` as suggested by @nIcEcOw, override `paintComponent(Graphics)` instead of `paint()`.  Again, call the `super` method first.
3. Don't extend frame, just use an instance of one. Set the size according to the space required for the components using `pack()`.